# Team City Command Line Build Runner

Tags: command-line, build-process, build-automation, teamcity

In Team City, we are currently using a command line build runner.  While it works just fine,  we don't get any output shown in the Team City log.  We essentially get a notification that the process started, and that the process exited with a particular exit code.

Is there a way to pipe the output of the command line call to the log so that we can see it from the Team City UI?

EDIT:  The command line call is just to devenv.com.  I tried the same call inside a NAnt script hoping that it would somehow catch the output -- and it didn't.  The reason I need to call devenv directly is that we have a handful of setup projects inside our solution.

EDIT 2:  I have restarted our build server, and output is now correctly being thrown into the log.

Comment: Usually output of the process should be shown in the build log. What process are you running using the command line runner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the build server fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, build log has two parts - important messages and all messages. Non-error messages usually go to "all messages".